# JQUERY slider mad

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

the site is http://www.quadrifoglio4.it/index.php/quadrifoglio4/gallery.html

the slide when slide 12 or 13 pics, not work fine, the left value of animate set to 0 and to good position.. the code is:

```
ogreGalleryStart = window.setInterval(function(){
            var ogreGalleryRailCurrentPosition = __jQuery__('#ogreRail').position();
            __jQuery__('.preloadThis').css('display','none');
            __jQuery__('#ogreRail').animate({
                left: eval(ogreGalleryRailCurrentPosition.left-__jQuery__('#ogreRail > .ogreDrawer').eq(0).outerWidth(true))+'px'
            }, 500, function(){
                var ogreGalleryRailCurrentPosition = __jQuery__('#ogreRail').position();
                if (ogreGalleryRailCurrentPosition.left <= -eval(__jQuery__('#ogreRail').outerWidth(true)-__jQuery__('#ogreRail > .ogreDrawer').eq(0).outerWidth(true))) {
                    __jQuery__(this).css({
                        'left': '0px'
                    });
                }
            });
        }, 4000);
```

why?

Comment: Why do you need these calls to `eval()`?

Comment: infact is not important... why? is this the problem? :S

Comment: I don't think so, but using `eval()` is generally not a good idea, so I wanted to know if some of your logic depended on it.